# How do I get the sum of values under a diagonal in numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Given a 2D rectangular numpy array:

```
a = np.array([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
])
```

I would like to take the sum of all values under the lower left to upper right  diagonal , I.E. `8`, `9` and `6`.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

The method should work for large arrays too.

Comment: What are you considering diagonal? I do not know why 9 is included.

Comment: "Diagonal" as in 'towards the right and downwards of the secondary diagonal', perhaps?

Comment: good point. Its the lower left to upper right diagonal. Edited the question.

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will help community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate, sum the upper triangle, and subtract the diagonal.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
result = np.triu(np.rot90(a)).sum() - np.trace(a)
#Output: 23
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.flip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) + [`np.tril`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html#numpy.tril) + [`np.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

print(np.sum(np.tril(np.flip(a, 1), -1)))
# 23
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform` to select your triangle of interest:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform
squareform(a[::-1], checks=False)
# array([8, 9, 6])
squareform(a[::-1], checks=False).sum()
# 23
```